# InputStream read part of file and output

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a set of large files ( about 2-3GB each) and I need to use `InputStream` to read it and output part of it to a new file.

```
//this is just for example
int size=100; 
String src="pathtofile";
OutputStream os = null; 
Inputstream is = new FileInputStream(new File(src));
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
byte[] bufferis = getBytesFromIS(is); 

buffer=Arrays.copyOfRange(bufferis,0,buffer.length);

String tempstr=new String(buffer);  
byte[] tempBytes=Arrays.copyOfRange(bufferis, buffer.length,is.available());
os = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest));
copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(tempBytes), os); //function writing to file
```

This works fine with small files but when using on large files, I keep getting `OutOfMemoryError`, even when I set `-Xmx6114m`, still getting `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Try instead Printwriter it can handle for your 2GB data ....

Comment: The answer here may be strikingly simple: Don't read the whole file when you need only a small part of it! Is there any reason to use `InputStream`? Although streams are often more versatile, this particular use case could be solved far more easily with a `RandomAccessFile`...

Comment: You need to eliminate `bufferis`. You could do `int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);`

Comment: @Marco13 the reason i have to use InputStream is that the file is encrypted

Comment: i suppose there is a way to strip some bytes from inputstream ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum array length is slightly less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i.e., about `2e9`. So you can't read the whole into a `byte[]` and have to use something else. A `ByteByffer` is probably the fastest solution (memory mapped file).

Comment: @user2324644 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-

Comment: turns out with bytebuffer, still cannot handle file size over 3gb

Comment: @user2324644 You can. You can't create a single `ByteBuffer` for the whole file, but you can use the `position` constructor argument.

Comment: yes i figured that, but the problem is i need to create a inputscream from those buffers

Answer (score 1):

You don't show `getBytesFromIS(is)` but assuming that it reads the entire file, that's not necessary.

The easiest way is to use a library that already provides this functionality and is fully tested. For example, [Apache Commons IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#read(java.io.InputStream,%20byte[],%20int,%20int)).

Otherwise, you can use [InputStream.read(b, off, len)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-), starting from an offset of 0 and with your desired length. *Beware, however, that this function is **not** guaranteed to read the entire amount of data that you want.*

Comment: by using IOUtils, the file inputstream still is loaded into byte buffer, so i assume that there still gonna be memory error if im not mistaken

Comment: IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream) this still wont work due to the size problem

Comment: @user2324644 - `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream)` isn't the function in the link.